# Actions are assigned to wrong keyframe in Flash CS5

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I am working with Flash CS5, and haven't been using Flash since the age of AS2.

I have a movieclip symbol in which I have an Actions layer, in which I have a keyframe in frame 1 and one in frame 20. Each of these should have a stop(); action assigned, but when i select the one in frame 20 and start writing, the little "a" appears on frame 1 of another layer. When I make a keyframe in frame 20 of that layer and try to assign actions it yields the same result. They appear on frame 1.

Is this a bug or am I missing some vital information about AS3?

Comment: Well, I just found a "workaround". If I open the actions window and then select frame 20 it will work. Still a weird bug though.

Comment: Are you sure You're making a "keyframe" and not a "frame"?

Comment: Yup. I know the difference ;)

Answer (score 0):

AS3 is in fact more picky (for good reason) about how the code is implemented.

You need to select the keyframe you are intending to put code into, and then use your actions window. And as Markus commented, make sure you're using keyframes, and not empty frames. If you try to write code into an empty frame, it will default it to the most recent keyframe.

Furthermore, If you have multiple layers and say, your code is on layer2 and your objects on layer1, if you have keyframes on layer1, and intend to enter code at frame 20, but your layer selection is layer2, it will yield the same result described above. You'll have to make sure the correct layer is active. The actions window will only display the code from the current layer's most recent keyframe.

Hope that clears some things up!

Comment: Yeah it seems like it was some sort of glitch.. After I selected the frame after opening the actions-window, I couldn't replicate the error..